# How to code GUI for logic design in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, simulator, circuit

I am a beginner coder in Java, just learning how to code for the GUI. My concern is I am not getting the part where I will be able to show various logic gates (AND, OR, etc) according to the input function. I have written the code for Boolean Simplification, now all I have to do to show that in LOGIC DIAGRAM. 
But I really dont know what to do for that purpose,as I am new to GUI.
Any direction/link/tutorial regarding this will be highly helpful. Thnks in advance.

Comment: no gui code for that boolean function yet, I m just learning gui from deitel. what codes you wanted @maheeka ?

Comment: Take a look at the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: You should also look at JavaFX which is touted to replace Swing.

Comment: @user3086871 post your Boolean Simplification code and explain what you want the GUI to do.

Comment: thanks both of you for the direction
actually simplification is not of concern here, the concern is if i get the final result like AB+A' then i want to be able show appropriate gates in the interface @bcorso

Comment: Hmm, well the problem is that you're not likely going to get a good answer on SO unless you rephrase your question into a short specific question and show what effort you've tried so far. Usually they close questions like this because the answers are too "opinionated".

Comment: hmm my code is in primarily in C syntax and it is huge so far :/ @bcorso

Comment: Well not saying you need to show "simplification" code if it doesn't apply, but you should try to show something or at least what you have tried whether it's code or just more specifically what don't you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Jgraph](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx) or [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/applet/index.html) in order to create a graph where the nodes of the graph are gates and the links between are wires. Both libraries have nice layout managers so your schematic will look nice by default.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a this example. What is does is separate the logic from the GUI.  I used a simple example of a `BooleanSimplification` class that only has one method. All that method does add two numbers together and returns the result.

What should interest you is how All I did was create an instance of the `BooleanExpresson` class in the GUI, and all I have to do is invoke it's method to get the logical operation method. To mke the GUI more manageable, this is that way you want to go. Keep the data and logic seperate from the GUI.

First you can see the `BooleanSimplification` class

```
class BooleanSimplification {

    public BooleanSimplification() {
    }

    public double add(double num1, double num2) {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

Then my GUI class. All it is, is a simple calculator that has two input fields and a result input field and button to calculate

[image]

You can copy and paste the following code. Try and follow the comments in the code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestRun extends JPanel {

    JLabel jlblnum1 = new JLabel("Number1");     // number 1 label
    JLabel jlblnum2 = new JLabel("Number2");     // number 2 label
    JLabel jlblresult= new JLabel("result");     // result label

    JTextField jtfnum1 = new JTextField(10);     // number1 text field
    JTextField jtfnum2 = new JTextField(10);     // number 2 text field
    JTextField jtfresult = new JTextField(10);   // result text field

    JButton getResult = new JButton("Get Result");   // get result button

    // instance of class here
    BooleanSimplification bs = new BooleanSimplification();  // the class

    public TestRun() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 2));  // panel to hold components
        panel.add(jlblnum1);
        panel.add(jtfnum1);
        panel.add(jlblnum2);
        panel.add(jtfnum2);
        panel.add(jlblresult);
        panel.add(jtfresult);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(getResult, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // here is where everything goes on.
        getResult.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(jtfnum1.getText());  // get number from text field
                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(jtfnum2.getText());  // get number from text field

                double result = bs.add(num1, num2);  // call the method from the BooleanSimplification class to handle my logic

                jtfresult.setText(String.valueOf(result));  // set the text of result with the result from the method

            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new TestRun());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

}

class BooleanSimplification {

    public BooleanSimplification() {
    }

    public double add(double num1, double num2) {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

Once you create an instance of the class, you can use all of its data and method in the GUI

Answer (score 1):

Use swing. It is not difficult to learn. Netbeans has inbuilt swing gui builder. You can use that. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/.